# What's the purpose of handlebars.js new method of iteration?

Tags: mustache, handlebars.js

In [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html), you iterate like this:

```
{{#items}}
  <div>The item {{item}}</div>
{{/items}}
```

In [handlebars.js](http://www.handlebarsjs.com/), there is a block helper `each` that lets you use an alternative syntax:

```
{{#each items}}
  <div>The item {{item}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Assuming I'm using handlebars, why would I use one syntax instead of the other? Which do you use, and why?

In Yehuda Katz's [blog post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/09/09/announcing-handlebars-js/) introducing handlebars, he talks about how block helpers allow him to remove the special casing needed to implement iteration in normal mustache syntax. Is this the only reason the `each` syntax exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up asking Yehuda on Twitter. [Here's his reply](https://twitter.com/#!/wycats/status/139484777026822146):

"two off the top of my head: performance and it's easier to understand"